# popToRootViewControllerAnimated in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

I am using Storyboard in my app in which there is a Main page from which the user can go to Tools page and from Tools page to SubTools Page i.e.

```
  Main-->Tools-->SubTools
```

All the segues are performed using `Push`.

Now I have a Home button which will take the user to the Main page. I am using

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to pop to the root view controller. This works fine in `ios7` but when I try to use it in `ios8` this doesn't do anything so I changed it to

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now the problem in using this is that when this is called from SubTools page then instead of jumping to the Main page it just jumps to the Tools page.

I checked the size of the array that is returned in `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` which in `ios7` is 2, which is correct as there are the Main page and Tools page in the stack, but in `ios8` the size of the array is 1.

Has anyone else faced this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting a bit I used a loop to iterate through the controllers as follows

```
NSArray *controllers= [self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
do
{
   controllers = [((UIViewController *)[controllers objectAtIndex:0]).parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}while(controllers.count>0);
```